# How do I make SQL Python find if a username is already in the database?

Tags: python, sql, mysql-python

This is my first time using SQL and I am very confused. I want python to check if a username is already in the database. For example, someone writes 'register' it will take their username and check if they are already there. I have code but it definitely doesn't work. It just checks and does nothing.

```
mycursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM TestDatabase WHERE name=%s""", (Username))
```

I want it to give something back. Like, at least give an error. This way I can use the 'try' thing. Is there a way to get an output from this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are using an ORM like sql alchemy it will be easier

Comment: mycursor.fetchall()

Comment: Justin Ezequiel, it worked. I used the 'try' thing to remove any expected errors and then everything worked. I just can't close this post. I suggest you make this comment an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mycursor.execute` by itself only prepares and executes the query, but it will **not** give you the result.

To get the result, you'll have to use one of the cursor's fetch methods, such as `fetchone()`, `fetchmany()`, or `fetchall()`.

Example:

```
mycursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM TestDatabase WHERE name=%s""", (Username,))
rows = mycursor.fetchall()
```

Then you can check `rows` afterwards.

You can find more information on the cursor methods here:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

Follow-up:

Note that the parameters must be an iterable, e.g. a tuple or a list, even if you're only passing one parameter to the cursor.

This will fail:

```
mycursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM TestDatabase WHERE name=%s""", (Username))
```

To make it a tuple add a `,` after Username:

```
mycursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM TestDatabase WHERE name=%s""", (Username,))
```

or make it a list:

```
mycursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM TestDatabase WHERE name=%s""", [Username])
```

Comment: it was working but now I keep getting the error "Could not process parameters"