# Python MySQL not inserting string variables

Tags: python, mysql

I am simply trying to insert two values pulled from a form in html. Using Flask and mysql.connector too

This is my index.html:

```
<h1>Simple Login Form</h1>

<form action="/signup" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" required/>
    <input type="password" name="password" required/>
    <input type="submit"/> </form>
```

And my line in python(app.py):

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=["POST"])
def signup():
    username = str(request.form["username"])
    password = str(request.form["password"])
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES({},{})".format(username, password))
    #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES('test','test')")
    mydb.commit()
```

For whatever reason I get internal server error when executing the first cursor but the '#' cursor code works fine... please could someone tell me where I am going wrong here.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47458189/ (even though it's SQLite, MySQL just uses ``%s`` instead of ``?`` for the prepared statements). TL;DR:  use ``VALUES('{}','{}')`` instead of ``VALUES({},{})`` - or even better, use prepared statements. Example of MySQL prepared statements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65915872/4349415

Answer (score 0):

Your values aren't quoted. Put the formatted strings into quotation marks, or, better, use bind variables and placeholders to execute it safely:

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)", [username, password])
```

See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html for more.

Comment: Trying this still gave me the same error, is there something I need to import for this? My code just really doesn't like inserting these strings but its fine if I use them in quotes

Comment: If you're using quotes then any special characters within the strings (e.g. other quotes) will affect the syntax of the statement. It's a very bad idea to use quotes and leaves your code open to SQL injections. Bind variables avoid all that; there isn't anything special to be imported in order to use them: They should always be used for values.

Comment: Your error logs (depending on your web server) should usually have the text of the error, which should be more informative than the generic Internal Server Error message that is displayed in the browser.

Comment: cursor.py", line 568, in execute
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: What parameters could I possibly be missing?

Comment: You definitely have your two variables inside an array? That could be one cause of that error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working, it was as simple as changing:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES({},{})".format(username, password))
```

To:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES('{}','{}')".format(username, password))
```

Simply changed the {}, {} to '{}', '{}'

Sadly no other methods worked for me and only this one is giving me the result I needed.

Thanks Mike Scotty